# Repeat Headers in Visual force Page

Tags: css, header, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Dear CSS/Salesforce gurus,

I am looking for a solution where the headers derived from many tables needs to be printed on all the pages (as headers) as soon as the page-break is applied. I am not able to print the headers apart from the first page.Also i need to make sure that the data table values are not split in different pages. Please assist me.

Please look my code below

Please help me with a head-start on this!!!

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;-fs-table-paginate: paginate;" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border-left: 1px solid #000000;font-size:9px;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iSerial_No].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iSerial_No].English__c}</th>
      <th style="font-size:9px;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iItem_Code_Desc].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iItem_Code_Desc].English__c}</th>
      <th style="font-size:9px;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iQuantity].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iQuantity].English__c}</th>
      <th style="font-size:9px;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iUnit].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iUnit].English__c}</th>
      <th style="font-size:9px;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iUnit_Price].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iUnit_Price].English__c}</th>


      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IsCustomerQuote}">
        <th>{!mapQuotationVariables[iDiscount].Arabic__c}
          <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iDiscount].English__c}</th>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000000;">{!mapQuotationVariables[iItem_total].Arabic__c}
        <br/>{!mapQuotationVariables[iItem_total].English__c}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <apex:variable var="sr" value="{!1}" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstQuoteLineItem}" var="qLine">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">{!sr}</td>
        <td style="border-style: solid;">

          <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 8px;">
            <tr style="height:4px;">
              <td width="33%" style="text-align:left;padding:0px;">
                {!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode}
              </td>
              <td width="33%" style="text-align:right;padding:0px;">
                {!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Manufacturer__r.Name}
              </td>
              <td width="33%" style="text-align:right;padding:0px;">
                {!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Manufacturer__r.Country__c}
              </td>

            </tr>

            <tr width="100%" style="height:3px;">
              <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left;padding:2px;">
                {!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="100%" style="height:3px;">
              <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left;padding:2px;">
                {!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Arabic_Product_Name__c}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="100%" style="height:3px;">
              <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left;padding:2px;">
                <apex:outputText value="{!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Description_Split__c}" escape="false" />
                <!--<output><apex:outputText value="{!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Description_Split__c}"/></output>-->
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>
        <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">
          <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}">
            <apex:param value="{!qLine.Quantity}" />
          </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">{!qLine.PricebookEntry.Product2.Unit__c}</td>
        <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">
          {!Quote.CurrencyISOCode} &nbsp;
          <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}" rendered="{!!IsCustomerQuote}">
            <apex:param value="{!qLine.Customer_List_Price__c}" />
          </apex:outputText>

          <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}" rendered="{!IsCustomerQuote}">
            <apex:param value="{!qLine.Customer_List_Price__c}" />
          </apex:outputText>

        </td>

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IsCustomerQuote}">
          <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">
            {!Quote.CurrencyISOCode} &nbsp;
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}" rendered="{!IsCustomerQuote}">
              <apex:param value="{!qLine.Customer_Discount_Amount__c}" />
            </apex:outputText>
          </td>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <td style="border-style: solid;vertical-align: top;">
          {!Quote.CurrencyISOCode} &nbsp;
          <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}" rendered="{!!IsCustomerQuote}">
            <apex:param value="{!qLine.Customer_List_Price_Total__c}" />
          </apex:outputText>

          <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0}" rendered="{!IsCustomerQuote}">
            <apex:param value="{!qLine.Customer_List_Price_Total__c - qLine.Customer_Discount_Amount__c}" />
          </apex:outputText>

        </td>
        <apex:variable var="sr" value="{!sr + 1}" />
        <div style="page-break-before:always;" />



      </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Thanks,

 Raja

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print { table {page-break-inside: avoid;} }
```

Add the above css styling to avoid data cells being split at the end of the page.

---

```
table {-fs-table-paginate: paginate;}
```

Add the above css styling to repeat the headers on each page.